# Insert BLOB type image to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, windows-8.1

I have created a database using:

```
create table test.data(
  id int not null,
  description varchar(255),
  image blob not null,
  primary key (id)
);
```

This worked. Then I try to insert data into the table using:

```
insert into test.data
values(1, "Image one", LOAD_FILE('D:\Ecommerce\site\image1.jpg'));
```

But I ended up with an error saying `column 'image' cannot be null`

How can I insert an image to a mysql database? I'm using MySQL Query Browser and Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

LOAD_FILE returns null. Try the following:

- double escape the slahes in the file path (for Win).
- The FILE privilege must be explicily granted for your mysql user. Make sure you have it enabled.

If it doesn't work check the 
[LOAD_FILE_Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file)
and make sure all conditions are meet.

Comment: Double escape the slashes in the file path is worked.                                                                               (.....load_file('C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\image1.jpg'));) Thank you